# Build error in Visual Studio application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a solution that I am trying to build in Visual Studio which gives the following error.
Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Copy the executable to HAMR platform"

The last few lines of the build log are as follows:

Copy the executable to HAMR platform
The system cannot find the path specified.
Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Copy the executable to HAMR platform"

I understand that there may be a wrong path mentioned in the code but as there is no line number to the error I don't know how to detect the source of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Post build error.

Go to Project Properties => Build Event =>Post-Build Event.

Check the command line values.

I guess you are trying to copy the source file which does not exist on the mentioned path.

Please check your output file is getting copied to the expected path or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a source code error. It's a build step error. Right click on the project, go to settings, and check the "Build Events" tab.